# Read JSON string as key value

Tags: c#, json, jsonfx

I have following json:

```
{   
    "serverTime": "2013-08-12 02:45:55,558",
    "data": [
        {
            "key1": 1,
            "key2": {},
            "key3": {
                "key4": [
                    ""
                ],
                "key5": "test2"
            },
            "key7": 0
        },
        {
            "key8": 1,
            "key9": {},
            "key10": {
                "key4": [
                    ""
                ],
                "key9": "test2"
            },
            "key11": 0
        }
    ] 

}
```

I want to get values as key value pair. Something like:

```
jsonObject[data][0]
```

should give first item of the **data** array.

I am using JSONFx.net. But it gives strongly typed objects. I do not want that.
Is there any way to parse JSON as key value as I mentioned earlier?

Thanks

Comment: It's because the json you wrote here is not an array but an object. And this object is holding an array(data) in it. The way you'll extract the array out of this json object is up to you. Right now there exist useful methods in answers though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("input.txt");
        var a = new { serverTime = "", data = new object[] { } };
        var c = new JsonSerializer();
        dynamic jsonObject = c.Deserialize(new StringReader(json), a.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.data[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not averse to using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), you can do this:

```cs
var jsonString = @"
{   
    ""serverTime"": ""2013-08-12 02:45:55,558"",
    ""data"": [
        {
            ""key1"": 1,
            ""key2"": {},
            ""key3"": {
                ""key4"": [
                    """"
                ],
                ""key5"": ""test2""
            },
            ""key7"": 0
        },
        {
            ""key8"": 1,
            ""key9"": {},
            ""key10"": {
                ""key4"": [
                    """"
                ],
                ""key9"": ""test2""
            },
            ""key11"": 0
        }
    ] 
}";

var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
var firstItem = jsonResult["data"][0];
```

`firstItem` would be an array of the first item in the `data` array:

[image: Demo result]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First create classes to parse string

```
public class Key2
{
}

public class Key3
{
    public List<string> key4 { get; set; }
    public string key5 { get; set; }
}

public class Key9
{
}

public class Key10
{
    public List<string> key4 { get; set; }
    public string key9 { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int key1 { get; set; }
    public Key2 key2 { get; set; }
    public Key3 key3 { get; set; }
    public int key7 { get; set; }
    public int? key8 { get; set; }
    public Key9 key9 { get; set; }
    public Key10 key10 { get; set; }
    public int? key11 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string serverTime { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

add reference of Newtonsoft.Json.dll

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
```

then you can access values .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without third party libraries then do:

I would use the following code:

```
var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var someObject = deserializer.DeserializeObject(json);

string serverTime = someObject["serverTime"].ToString();
Dictionary<string, int> data = someObject["data"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
```

Give it a go.

Edit: You may need to change the last line to:

```
Dictionary<string, int?> data = someObject["data"] as Dictionary<string, int?>;
```