# How to get value from a string which is formatted as JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, string

I have a string with a formatting like this:

```
[["addr","field"],["Administrator@cadomain.com",1000],["test1@cadomain.com",1001],["test2@cadomain.com",1002],["67656x3434",100],["99999",511],["79898",400],["545654",561],["7979",200],["6776767",201],["4656",300],["88888",5000]]
```

I want to get the addre (value) base on the field (key).
I read some article about how to get value from a JSON string at:

[Read JSON string as key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185967/read-json-string-as-key-value)

[How to read this json string using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831109/how-to-read-this-json-string-using-c)

But it does not work for me.

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: And for some language?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. I use C# language, Deep

Comment: Well, and i wanted write js solution ))) And c# not have lib for json parse?

Comment: C# has JsonObject class for json parse. But the problem is my string is not a JSON, just likes as its format.

Comment: Your example is pure JSON. Parse it with library. And after make your inner format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library to parse the JSON, you can get the data into a `Dictionary<int, string>` like this:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);

Dictionary<int, string> dict = 
    token.Skip(1).ToDictionary(a => (int)a[1], a => (string)a[0]);
```

Then you can use the dictionary like you normally would to access the data.

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Icyv1O

---

If you can only use .Net 2.0, you can do the same thing like this:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

bool skippedFirstItem = false;
foreach (JToken item in token)
{
    if (skippedFirstItem)
        dict.Add((int)item[1], (string)item[0]);
    else
        skippedFirstItem = true;
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zDvQFF

Comment: This is an answer that I need. How about your solution in case of using .NET 2.0 which does not support Lamda Expression?

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to show how to do this in .NET 2.0